# Error: require inputStream, found inputStreamReader

Tags: java

I am wrote a program that is suppose to read the text of web page and I am followed an example i found in this web page, but java is complaining: It says that i have an "incomparable type: require inputStream, found inputStreamReader." I googled the error message to see if I can find any insight but I dint find anything relevant. My code is below and I have commented "Problem Line" right above the line that is generating the error.

As always, I appreciate any help you guys offer.

```
package com.learn.java;

import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net. * ;
import java.io. * ;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://news.google.com//news");
            URLConnection site = url.openConnection();

            //Problem Line (below)
            InputStream line = new InputStreamReader(site.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader lineBuffered = new BufferedReader(line);

            while (true) {
                int count = 0; ++count;
                String lineRead = lineBuffered.readLine();
                if (lineRead != null) {
                    System.out.print(count + ". " + lineRead + "\n");
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {}

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgat to include the hyperlink to the web page i mentioned in my question. Here it is: http://java.sys-con.com/node/39248

Comment: Reader line = new InputStreamReader(site.getInputStream());

Comment: InputStream is not the super class of InputSreamReader              . Use this way              
 FileReader line = new InputStreamReader(site.getInputStream());

Comment: Salvatore Napoli and  Karthikeyan Subramaniam, you guys lead me in the right direction and i caught my own error: I initialized my "line" variable as inputStream rather than inputStreamReader. I corrected these and java stopped complaining; that was what it didn't like.